# Derivative with matrices and Traces

Tags: matrix-calculus, trace

Given $F, L \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, consider

$$ \mathcal{L}:= tr(F^TLF)$$

Now I would like to compute $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial F}$ but I'm always a bit stuck computing derivatives when dealing with matrices.

ATTEMPT:

we can write $tr(F^TLF) = \sum_{i=1}^n F_i^TLF_i$, then

$$\frac{\partial tr(F^TLF)}{\partial F} =\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial F_i^TLF_i}{\partial F_i} = \sum_{i=1}^n2F_iL = 2FL$$

Answer (score 2):

Suggestion:

I would suggest not to go for elementwise derivatives, as it is prone to error.

---

Solution:

Let us define the Frobenius product by a colon and use it's cyclic property
\begin{align}
{\rm Tr}\left( A^T B C \right) 
&:= A: BC \\
&= AC^T: B \\
&= B^TA:C
\end{align}

Let
\begin{align}
\phi(F) := {\rm Tr}\left( F^T L F \right)  \equiv F: LF.
\end{align}

Now, we can use differentials and then obtain gradient.
\begin{align}
d\phi &= dF: LF + F:LdF \\
      &= LF: dF + L^T F:dF \\
      &= \left( L + L^T \right) F: dF
\end{align}

The gradient is
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial F} = \left( L + L^T \right) F.
\end{align}

Comment: What do you mean by : ?

Comment: It's just a "notation"

Comment: to indicate what?

Comment: @JamesArten $\langle A^T, B C \rangle = \operatorname{Tr}(A^T BC) := A : BC$. So, this colon notation is convenient to use. You can keep trace if you like.